# Cant get the background colour to change

Tags: html, css

**I'm currently learning Html and CSS**

I have been following courses  for a few days and been doing a Udemy course as i learn better with visual aid over just reading texts.

I'm currently trying to get the background of the website to change colder etc and i have copied the code word for word and it worked for them but it hasn't for me I've linked the css and html file and they are both in the same folder.

Picture blow

[Html file that has the css file linked with code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqJ2D.png)

[Css file with the code to change html and body background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YntPe.png)

"These isn't the colours I'm going with just trying bright to see if can get them to change"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

use href

Comment: OMG i never felt so dumb! never noticed u used the wrong attribute ive spent 20 mins looking to see wtf i done wrong.
Thanks